# SQL Workbench/J WbDataDiff TimeStampt

Tags: sql-workbench-j

I'm executing data diff command in SQL-Workbench/J to compare two PostgreSQL 10 tables. As following

```
WbDataDiff -referenceProfile="prod"
           -targetProfile="dev"
           -referenceTables=public."Product"
           -file=migrate_staging.sql
           -includeDelete=false
           -sqlDateLiterals="ansi"
```

But the SQL output of the command is not compatible with the SQL. Notice in the following example Timestamp should have been like '2020-07-14T16:00:48.918167' with no spaces and with single quotes. I've tried "ansi", "dbms" and "default" for the parameter sqlDateLiterals, but the output was the same.

```
UPDATE "Product"
   SET "UpdateDate" = 2020 -07 -14 T16:00:48.918167
WHERE "OID" = 11109;
```

So how can I output the proper Timestamp format using this command?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the current dev build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug that has been fixed in the dev build as of 15/07/2020